# How do I ignore a pymongo ServerSelectionTimeoutError on attempting to connect to a replica set where one of the mongo server is down?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-replica-set, pymongo-3.x

I have a client connection to mongo like so -

```
 self.mongoClient = pymongo.MongoClient(environ.get("MONGO_URL"),
                                                   username=environ.get(
                                                   "MONGO_USERNAME", default=""),
                                                   password=environ.get(
                "MONGO_PASSWORD", default=""),
                authSource=environ.get(
                "MONGO_AUTH_DB", default=""),
                replicaSet=environ.get("MONGO_REPLICATION", default="rs-0"))
```

My MONGO_URL in this case is --

```
MONGO_URL=127.0.0.1:27011,127.0.0.1:27012,127.0.0.1:27013,10.10.0.1:27014,127.0.0.1:27015
```

The assumption made here is that one or more of the services might be down at any given time (this isn't ideal for production, but we're testing something out)
Eg, when we try to connect, assume that 127.0.0.1:27012 and 10.10.0.1:27014 is down. As in, there is no mongo server listening on those ports.

I hit upon the error below:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:27012: [Errno 111] Connection refused,10.10.0.1:27014: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 65390c7f67d64862d4e035f5, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('127.0.0.1', 27012) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('127.0.0.1:27012: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>, <ServerDescription ('10.10.0.1', 27014) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('10.10.0.1:27014: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

Considering that the primary at this point (127.0.0.1:27011) and the rest are alive and working, how do I nudge the client to ignore the ones that give connection refuced and move ahead?

Comment: All failover logic is on the driver side and should work as long as you specified correct replica set name. Also you should not specify all server names explicitly. It's a driver side logic to get these servers from hello.members data. What does `{ hello : 1 }` return you?